# How can i get a value to be more exact in Java

Tags: java

I have just started learning Java and I can't seem to get this calculator to work.
I want to have a variable amount, and from that, calculate the least number of coins needed to make this amount.

This is my program:

```
double amount, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;
int quartersNeeded, dimesNeeded, nickelsNeeded, penniesNeeded;

amount  = 1.63;
quarters = 0.25;
dimes = 0.1;
nickels = 0.05;
pennies = 0.01;

quartersNeeded = (int)(amount / quarters);
amount = amount - (quartersNeeded * 0.25);

dimesNeeded = (int)(amount / dimes);
amount = amount - (dimesNeeded * 0.1);

nickelsNeeded = (int)(amount / nickels);
amount = amount - (nickelsNeeded * 0.05);

penniesNeeded = (int)(amount / pennies);
amount = amount - (penniesNeeded * 0.01);
System.out.println(amount);

System.out.println(quartersNeeded);
System.out.println(dimesNeeded);
System.out.println(nickelsNeeded);
System.out.println(penniesNeeded);
```

Quarters, dimes, and nickels seem to work fine but once it gets to pennies, the amount is something like 0.0099999999999887 and penniesNeeded is always short one if the hundredth place of the initial amount is 3,4,7,8,9.

Comment: Ah yes, this issue shows up in Effective Java by Bloch.

Comment: This is a floating point number problem, not java specific. If you are just learning java it will be hard to explain thoroughly but its related to the maximum precision of floating point numbers, to solve this you will have to account for the loss of precision

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Related articles about NOT using doubles when exact answers are needed, and DON'T use them for currency: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/NUM04-J.+Do+not+use+floating-point+numbers+if+precise+computation+is+required

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

https://www.google.com/search?q=exact+answer+do+not+use+double+float+java

Comment: You can use a [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), and a [MathContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html) to be as precise as you want.

Comment: The Goldberg article isn't very newbie-friendly. Try http://floating-point-gui.de instead.

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with currency, you should never use floating point for this reason. Instead, use a integer type for the number of cents:

```
amount = 163;
final QUARTER = 25;
final DIME = 10;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to not use `double`. It is an IEEE 754 64-bit floating point number, and even such simple *decimal* values as 0.1 cannot be represented reliably as `double`s. Note "decimal": the way we write number is using base 10; with IEEE 754, floating point numbers use base 2.

Use `BigDecimal` instead. And if you care about performance, use [apfloat](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/).